# SharePoint Reporting Services NLB Configuration Problems with Routing

Tags: reporting-services, load-balancing, nlb

I have a problem with Reporting Service Integration on my environment.

We have 2 WFE's. Reporting services is configured on both. However, on the SharePoint Central Admin under reporting services integration, we have specified

```
http://server2/ReportingServices_Instance
```

as the reporting instance. I'm reading on some Microsoft Articles that I should use a NLB Address here. Anyways, I'm not sure if that's the cause.

My problem is that when browsing to

http:/server1/ReportsLibrary/

and clicking on some report, it redirects to

> http:/server2/ReportsLibrary/xxxxxwhatever

Why is it redirecting to server 2 when server 1 also has Reporting services configured? Even this is not a big issue.

This biggest issue is that we don't access the SharePoint environments using the server names directly,but via a hardware load balancer and a dns friendly name.

So, what's happening is that sometimes when browsing to

> http://myintranet.mydomain.com/ReportsLibrary

and clicking on a report, it gives a RS Error

> "For more information about this error navigate to the report server
>   on the local server machine, or enable remote errors "

I figured out that when this error occurs, the Load balancer is forcing the user to server1. Any idea how to fix this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to find and fix the problem. Everything was Kerberos related. I changed my web application to use Kerberos and then everything was working fine.